# Data Validation - Error alert cusotmized like If

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is it possible in Data Validation to use Error Alert with formula like IF
i need use specific error messages with specific results

for example

```
if(A1="Test";"result1";(if a1="Test1";"result2");"result3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive done this using VBA (Alt + F11). Right click on the sheet you want it in and click View Code. Paste this into your Sheet module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then
'if target is more than 1 cell
Else
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "A1" Then
        If Target = "Test" Then
            MsgBox "result1"
        Else
            If Target = "Test1" Then
                MsgBox "result2"
            Else
                MsgBox "result3"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```